# Nested for-loop debugging with matrix algorithm and constants.

Tags: c, matrix, sse, nested-loops, matrix-multiplication

This set of nested for loops works correctly for values of M=64 and N=64, but does not work when I make M=128 and N=64. I have another program that checks for correct values for the matrix multiply. Intuitively it seems like it should still work, but gives me the wrong answer.

```
for(int m=64;m<=M;m+=64){
for(int n=64;n<=N;n+=64){
    for(int i = m-64; i < m; i+=16){

        float *A_column_start, *C_column_start;
        __m128 c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, mul_1, 
               mul_2, mul_3, mul_4, b_1;
        int j, k;

        for(j = m-64; j < m; j++){

            //Load 16 contiguous column aligned elements from matrix C in
            //c_1-c_4 registers

            C_column_start = C+i+j*M;

            c_1 = _mm_loadu_ps(C_column_start);
            c_2 = _mm_loadu_ps(C_column_start+4);
            c_3 = _mm_loadu_ps(C_column_start+8);
            c_4 = _mm_loadu_ps(C_column_start+12);

            for (k=n-64; k < n; k+=2){

                //Load 16 contiguous column aligned elements from matrix A to
                //the a_1-a_4 registers

                A_column_start = A+k*M;

                a_1 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i);
                a_2 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+4);
                a_3 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+8);
                a_4 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+12);

                //Load a value to resgister b_1 to act as a "B" or ("A^T") 
                //element to multiply against the A matrix

                b_1 = _mm_load1_ps(A_column_start+j);

                mul_1 = _mm_mul_ps(a_1, b_1);
                mul_2 = _mm_mul_ps(a_2, b_1);
                mul_3 = _mm_mul_ps(a_3, b_1);
                mul_4 = _mm_mul_ps(a_4, b_1);

                //Add together all values of the multiplied A and "B"
                //(or "A^T") matrix elements

                c_4 = _mm_add_ps(c_4, mul_4);
                c_3 = _mm_add_ps(c_3, mul_3);
                c_2 = _mm_add_ps(c_2, mul_2);
                c_1 = _mm_add_ps(c_1, mul_1);

                //Move over one column in A, and load the next 16 contiguous 
                //column aligned elements from matrix A to the a_1-a_4 registers

                A_column_start+=M;

                a_1 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i);
                a_2 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+4);
                a_3 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+8);
                a_4 = _mm_loadu_ps(A_column_start+i+12);

                //Load a value to resgister b_1 to act as a "B" or "A^T"
                //element to multiply against the A matrix

                b_1 = _mm_load1_ps(A_column_start+j);

                mul_1 = _mm_mul_ps(a_1, b_1);
                mul_2 = _mm_mul_ps(a_2, b_1);
                mul_3 = _mm_mul_ps(a_3, b_1);
                mul_4 = _mm_mul_ps(a_4, b_1);

                //Add together all values of the multiplied A and "B" or
                //("A^T") matrix elements

                c_4 = _mm_add_ps(c_4, mul_4);
                c_3 = _mm_add_ps(c_3, mul_3);
                c_2 = _mm_add_ps(c_2, mul_2);
                c_1 = _mm_add_ps(c_1, mul_1);

            }
            //Store the added up C values back to memory

            _mm_storeu_ps(C_column_start, c_1);
            _mm_storeu_ps(C_column_start+4, c_2);
            _mm_storeu_ps(C_column_start+8, c_3);
            _mm_storeu_ps(C_column_start+12, c_4);

        }

    }
    }
}}
```

Comment: I love when ppl claim that solutions are simple when they are not able to find the answer themself ;)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger to see what loops get executed when? Your outer two loops will only be executed once each if M and N are both 64. I would also think about `#define`-ing the 64 and reducing it to some much smaller value to make a minimal test case to help you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your use of `M` in the code

```
C_column_start = C+i+j*M;
```

needs to be using `m` instead. Possibly also in other lines where you use `M`.
However, I do not really understand your code, since you did not explain what the code is intended to do, and I'm not a math programmer.

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly for M = 64 and N=64 because in these cases you are only doing one iteration in the corresponding looping (the two outer most). When you you have M = 128 you now do two steps on the outer loop in which case the line

```
C_column_start = C+i+j*M;
```

and the line

```
A_column_start = A+k*M;
```

Will produce the same results for the inner loop so essentially for the two steps you do on the outer loop (m=64,128) you are just doubling the result of one step with m=128. The fix is as simple as changing M to m so that you use the iteration variable.

Also you should consider aligning your data in A and C so that you can do SSE aligned loads. This will result in much faster code.